# What exactly happens when Blender 'Synchronizes objects' at render time?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

In effort to reduce render times between each frame (Eevee renderer), I've retopo-ed and made sure there are least amount of polygons possible, but I've reached the point where I can't sacrifice any more detail.

Now I'm tasked with finding out how to make blender 'Synchronize Objects' even faster after all of that (if possible).

Thing is, I don't know what Synchronizing Objects even means.
I'd really like to learn more about it but there is no information about it anywhere, so if anyone could explain to me what Synchronizing Objects means, I'd be very grateful.

Thank you!